# JavaFX generate executable in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have created a `JavaFX` aplication in `intelliJ` and now I would like to generate the `.exe` file of my project and I can't figure it out how can I do that.

I have learned how to generate the `.jar` file from `Project Structure -> artifacts` but I couldn't open it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I should convert the jar into an executable.

Comment: Have you tried selecting `all` instead of `exe` ?